# restkit mapping and inverse relationship

Tags: core-data, restkit

I have a small issue with relationship mapping in restkit.
I have a relationship in my model like the following:

News < -- >> Tag

In coredata I mapped this as:

> News: tags -> to-many, optional
>
> Tag:  news -> to-one, required.

Now... I have a JSON like the following:

```
{
   "news" : {
     "attr1" = "...",
     "tags" = ["tag1, "tag2, ...]
   }
}
```

I setup my mapping in this way (btw: my Tag entity has only one attribute: value)

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *tagMapping = [[self class] objectMappingForClass:[Tag class] inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [tagMapping mapKeyPath:@"" toAttribute:@"value"];

RKManagedObjectMapping *newsMapping = [[self class] objectMappingForClass:[News class] inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
....
[newsMapping mapKeyPath:@"Tags" toRelationship:@"tags" withMapping:tagMapping];
```

Now... when RestKit parses and maps the News JSON, it finds the tags attribute and it builds a list of Tag entities with the correct values. It also link this array/set to the tags relationship in News. But... my Tag entities have the news relationship set to nil, so it does not pass the CoreData validation.
How can I set up the inverse relationship? I tried to add the following statement:

```
[tagMapping mapRelationship:@"news" withMapping:newsMapping];
```

but I get an excetion..

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean the news json already contains tags. So, does tag object still contain news attributes inside it.

Comment: Sorry.. I don't understand your comment... I cannot retrieve the tags from the server, only the news. In the news json, each news has a list of tags. What I am asking is that RestKit fills correctly the relationship tags inside news (which is a `NSSet*`), but does not fill the inverse relationship that is news inside the Tag object (which is a `News*`)

Comment: So I understand the relationship tag inside news but what does news inside tag mean again.

Comment: @insane-36 it's the inverse relationship. CoreData strongly encourage its use. And I find them useful. So... if you have a reference to a Tag object you can follow the relationship news to find which news it is related...

Comment: @MariosCeid not yet. But to be honest I have never tried it again. In the mean time RestKit has changed quite a lot so maybe when I will some time I can try to see if the problem is still there.